# In my example, did I use parentheses correctly?

Tags: parentheses

As mentioned before, Table 1 is evidence that alcohol consumption was reduced by 9.2% (with statistical significance at the 1% level).

Should I remove or leave the parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter from a grammatical/punctuation viewpoint. It just depends on how relevant you think the contents of the brackets are to the main statement.

If it is entirely subsidiary it is best to use parentheses. But if it is of more significance, then remove the brackets and put a comma after 9.2%.